# How do I change the <title> in an IHP app?

Tags: haskell, ihp

I see `<title>App</title>` is hardcoded in `defaultLayout` in Web/View/Layout.hs, and Web/View/Context.hs has

```
    let viewContext = ViewContext {
            requestContext = ?requestContext,
            user = currentUserOrNothing,
            flashMessages,
            controllerContext = ?controllerContext,
            layout = let ?viewContext = viewContext in defaultLayout
        }
```

but how do I use a different function for a specific View? The `html` function of the View class doesn't seem to return a new context, just a new html for part of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a `pageTitle` function you could use in view (e.g. your layout) like this:

```hs
[hsx|
    <head>
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
    </head>
|]
```

https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/blob/18f104da69c526ff9e8ad3a6cdaedc6d39afb38c/IHP/PageTitle/ViewFunctions.hs#L54

Which can in turn be set in action using `setTitle`

```hs
action ShowProjectAction { projectId } = do
    project <- fetch projectId
    setTitle (get #title project)
```

https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/blob/d98c3d6eb8145d859c9ce461e7d1367be5be7337/IHP/PageTitle/ControllerFunctions.hs#L32

Latest IHP also generates the following layout s.t. you get it automatically with a fallback:

```hs
defaultLayout :: Html -> Html
defaultLayout inner = H.docTypeHtml ! A.lang "en" $ [hsx|
<head>
    {metaTags}

    {stylesheets}
    {scripts}

    <title>{pageTitleOrDefault "App"}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        {renderFlashMessages}
        {inner}
    </div>
</body>
|]
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out: There's a `beforeRender` function you can override in the `View` class where you can set it, e.g.

```
data ShowView = ShowView { targets :: [Include "comments" Post], postTitle :: Text }

instance View ShowView ViewContext where
    beforeRender (context, view) = (context { layout = myLayout (postTitle view) }, view)
    html ShowView { .. } = [hsx| … |]
```

(and set `postTitle` in Web/Controller/Posts.hs), then change Web/View/Layout.hs to do

```
defaultLayout :: Html -> Html
defaultLayout = myLayout "App"

myLayout :: Text -> Html -> Html
myLayout title inner = H.docTypeHtml ! A.lang "en" $ [hsx|
<head>
    {metaTags}

    {stylesheets}
    {scripts}

    <title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        {renderFlashMessages}
        {inner}
    </div>
</body>
|]
```